# Having difficulty getting value to post from dynamic dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

G'day,
I'm having a problem getting the right value to post on a form I've made. It is passing the ID but not the name.
Here's my code:

```
<td name="tech_userlogin" id="tech_userlogin" align="right" valign="top"><select name="tech_userlogin" id="tech_userlogin" class="db_field_name">

        <?php
        $sql="SELECT techID, tech_userlogin FROM technicians";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $options="";

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $techID=$row["techID"];
        $tech_userlogin=$row["tech_userlogin"];
        $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$techID\">$tech_userlogin</option>";
    }
    ?>

    <OPTION VALUE="">---Select---
    <?php echo $options; ?>
    </SELECT>
```

The form posts to this page:

```
<?php
include 'sql_connect_R.inc.php';

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['jobID']); 
$equip = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['wo_equip']);
$techID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['techID']);
$tech_login = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tech_userlogin']);

mysql_query("UPDATE work_orders SET wo_equip = UCASE('$equip'), wo_techID = '$techID', tech_userlogin = '$tech_login'
WHERE jobID = '$id'");

mysql_close($con);
```

I'm very new to PHP/MySQL and it took me a couple of days to get something that would put the tech_userlogin into a dropdown box. That is working, but when it posts the techID comes through on both $techID and $tech_userlogin.
Could someone please help me sort this out? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers, Spud

Comment: Why the name attribute on a TD? How are you retrieving the results? what does it mean "comes through on both $techID and $tech_userlogin" ?

Comment: As I said I'm very new at this. I don't have a good answer for naming the TD. It is part of a form that posts to another page for updating a table.Here is the code for that page:

Comment: Sorry for that. I've included the page the form posts to in an edit to the question. The wo_equip is updating and the techID in the work_orders table is updating, but the $tech_login is coming across with the techID value.

Comment: `<select name="tech_userlogin".......$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$techID\">$tech_userlogin</option>";` you're giving it the techID value!

Comment: LOL!! By golly, you're right! I've been staring at this thing for hours and I guess I couldn't see the forest for all the trees. Thanks for pointing out my incredibly obvious problem. Sometimes it takes another set of eyes. I've made the change and it's working like it should. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What seems to be happening is that you've named the select box "tech_userlogin", but in the option tags the value is set to the techid. Since the value is what's sent back in the $_REQUEST array, try something like this instead:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $tech_userlogin=$row["tech_userlogin"];
    $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$tech_userlogin\">$tech_userlogin</option>";
}
```

I believe that will give you what you want.

Comment: You are exactly right. I was staring at it so long looking for what was right in front of my eyes. I'm so new at this and I have a tendency to think I'm making major mistakes. Thank you for suggestion. I am bringing the techID over on a hidden field. It's all working as it should now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

On the form the $row['techID'] is being set to the drop down menu tech_userlogin (Ultimately $_POST['tech_userlogin']). There is a few ways to fix this.

1) POST both values in the value field of the option and seperate on the processing side by using:

```
 $techArray = explode(',',$string); 
 # $techArray[0] will be either the id or login
 # $techArray[1] will be the other
```

This is not recommended due to possible security issues.

2) Just past the techID through the dropdown box and have another query to get the user login information on the post page and use it to fill in the tech_userlogin field. Recommended

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is passing the tech id, is because when you submit a drop down list, the `value` is the ... well.. value.

If you want to pass the value and the name, you can do it through various means.

The first is to use Javascript (jQuery would be great) and you can bind a `change` event to the `tech_user_login` drop down. So when this changes, it can update a hidden input to the contents of the selected item in the list.

The second method would be to store the tech id and the tech logon name in the value of the option - so something like:

```
$techID=$row["techID"];
$tech_userlogin=$row["tech_userlogin"];
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$techID~~$tech_userlogin\">$tech_userlogin</option>";
```

Then when the value is posted, you can simply do something like `$array_tech = explode("~~",$_POST["tech_userlogin"]);` and use `$array_tech[0]` for the tech id and `$array_tech[1]` for the tech logon name.

Finally, you can just post the value and look up the tech logon using a second query on the next page.

Comment: I'm going to give this a try. I'm only a few weeks into it and I'm trying to absorb a lot. I appreciate learning new ways to do what I'm sure can be done. It is exciting learning these things, it keeps me young. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

first check in the value of selected in `include 'sql_connect_R.inc.php';` like `if(isset( $_REQUEST['tech_userlogin'] ))` this will will give you the value of the select box that is `<OPTION VALUE=\"$techID\">$tech_userlogin</option>`. Note that just provide the value `$techID`, not the `$tech_userlogin`. and if you want the result of `$tech_userlogin` then again run a query with its value that you will get through `$techID`.

hope this will help you